# Heroku custom name servers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been using a custom nameserver set up as seen below for three days:

```
example.harokuapp.com
```

However this doesn't seem to be working at all - I am receiving the following error:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to example.com.au
```

The Custom name server is setup from a domain registrar side and only one field is filled with the following value: `example.herokuapp.com` address

Is there a reason why this isn't working?

Comment: are no reason to not working, try `nslookup example.herokuapp.com`

Comment: does the command resolves the domain?

Comment: you can't resolve `example.com.au` with CNAME, only just `www.example.com.au`, and if you wish to use the CNAME you shall to ro redirect from `example.com.au` to `www.example.com.au`. In other case you shall to use ALIAS record if any

Comment: please refer to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919116/setting-up-custom-domain-on-heroku-with-cname/20919218#20919218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a DNS configuration problem.

Looking at your output from `dig www.virtualcareersfair.com.au` -

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.virtualcareersfair.com.au. 1800 IN  CNAME   dotconferences.herokuapp.com.virtualcareersfair.com.au.
```

In the DNSmadeeasy control panel edit your CNAME entry and pop a . (fullstop) at the end of dotconferences.herokuapp.com <- this in the Alias to box.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to make CNAME record with just the domain name `virtualcareersfair.com.au` without `www` but it's not working and coming up with error saying Field is required it's almost like I need to put subdomain in there otherwise it won't work. Is there a way to link main domain without `www` aswell?

Comment: in which case, you need to create an ANAME record on dnsnamedeasy to dotconferences.herokuapp.com. I suggest then you create an HTTP redirection record for www. to http://virtualcareersfair.com

Comment: > virtualcareersfair.com.au without www  but it's not working 

This is expected...

Comment: both work for me - although as I suggested I would use the dnsmadeeasy HTTP redirection entry to redirect www. to the naked domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you runned

```
heroku domains:add "example.com.au"
```

Heroku needs to know which domains to respond too.

Also make sure your DNS record is a **CNAME** to `example.com.au`

Comment: It's also possible to add the custom domain via [Heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com). Go to your app and click settings you will find **Domains** a bit down that page.

Comment: Yes this is already done for both example.com.au and www.example.com.au

Comment: If you're getting a Chrome error then the fault is with DNS setup, if you give us the real domain we can suggest fixes much quicker....

Comment: It's virtualcareersfair.com.au

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following steps:

1. Look whether that domain is being used by another heroku application or not. If so, delete it.
2. Run `heroku domains:add "example.com.au"` to add your domain. Or add it in the web configuration.

And that's it.